# How to configure dns entries for Docker Compose

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am setting up a Spring application to run using compose. The application needs to establish a connection to ActiveMQ either running locally for developers or to existing instances for staging/production.

I setup the following which is working great for local dev:

```
amq:
    image: rmohr/activemq:latest
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
legacy-bridge:
    image:  myco/myservice
    links:
      - amq
```

and in the application configuration I am declaring the AMQ connection as

```
broker-url=tcp://amq:61616
```

Running docker-compose up is working great, activeMQ is fired up locally and my application constiner starts and connects to it.

Now I need to set this up for staging/production where the ActiveMQ instances are running on existing hardware within the infrastructure. My thoughts are to either use spring profiles to handle a different configurations in which case the application configuration entry for 'broker-url=tcp://amq:61616' would become something like `broker-url=tcp://some.host.here:61616` or find some way to create a dns entry within my production docker-compose.yml which will point an `amq` dns entry to the associated staging or production queues.

What is the best approach here and if it is DNS, how to I set that up in compose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Using the `extra_hosts` flag

First thing that comes to mind is using [Compose's `extra_hosts`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/extrahosts) flag:

```
legacy-bridge:
  image:  myco/myservice
  extra_hosts:
    - "amq:1.2.3.4"
```

This will not create a DNS record, but an entry in the container's `/etc/hosts` file, effectively allowing you to continue using `tcp://amq:61616` as your broker URL in your application.

## Using an ambassador container

If you're not content with directly specifying the production broker's IP address and would like to leverage existing DNS records, you can use the [ambassador pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20191127090430/https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/ambassador_pattern_linking/):

```
amq-ambassador:
  image: svendowideit/ambassador
  command: ["your-amq-dns-name", "61616"]
  ports:
    - 61616
legacy-bridge:
  image:  myco/myservice
  links:
    - "amq-ambassador:amq"
```